# What is the maximum product from two fractions who sum to 1?

Tags: products, variance

I'm working on a problem where I need to prove that a posterior variance of binomial data with a uniform prior is less than 1/12 (the variance of the prior). Currently I have $(\frac{y+1}{n+2})$  $(\frac{n-y+1}{n+2})$ $(\frac{1}{n+3})$ For the variance. Since the first two fractions sum to 1, I know conceptually that the maximum product is $\frac14$. However, how can we prove that the maximum product of two fractions who sum to 1 is $\frac14$?

I know from there how to prove the inequality, but I just don't know how to prove the maximum product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two real numbers $0 < a, b$ such that $a + b = 1$, so $b = 1-a$. We want to maximize $a\cdot b$.

Substitution gives $a \cdot b = a(1-a) = a - a^2$. What is the maximum possible value of that expression?

Comment: So by differentiating with respect to a and setting equal to zero, we have 1 - 2a = 0, therefore a = 1/2. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We have two positive numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x + y = 1$. Also, for *any* real number, its square is positive, meaning that
$$
0 \leq (\sqrt x - \sqrt y)^2
$$
(I realise this looks like it comes out of nowhere, but as we see below, it's *exactly* what we need, so bear with me.) We continue working on that inequality to get
$$
0\leq x -2\sqrt{xy} + y = x+y-2\sqrt{xy}\\
2\sqrt{xy} \leq x + y= 1\\
\sqrt{xy}\leq \frac{1}{2}\\
xy\leq \frac14
$$
so we cannot do better than $0.25$. Is that value possible to reach? Well, note that the *first* line is an equality (instead of an *inequality*) when $\sqrt x - \sqrt y = 0$, or in other words, $x = y$. If we have $x = y$ and $x+y = 1$, then we must have $x = y = 0.5$, which does actually give $xy = 0.25$, so we are done.